# Vector subscript out of range on iterator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, outofrangeexception

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <fstream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

bool generateRandomValue()
{
    static std::default_random_engine e{};
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d{ 0, 100 };

    bool headsTails = (d(e) > 50) ? true : false;

    return headsTails;
}

int main()
{
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    ofstream outputFile("output.txt");

    int totalHeads = 0;
    int totalTails = 0;

    vector<int> headList(100,0);
    vector<int> tailList(100,0);

    for (int out = 0; out <= 100; out++)
    {
        char result = '\0';
        int heads = 0, tails = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            result = (generateRandomValue()) ? 'H' : 'T';

            if (result == 'H')
            {
                heads++;
            }

            else
            {
                tails++;
            }
        }

        outputFile << "Trial " << out << ": Heads: " << heads << " Tails: " << tails << endl << endl;
        headList.push_back(heads);
        tailList.push_back(tails);

    }

    for (vector<int>::iterator i = headList.begin(); i < headList.end(); i++)
    {
        totalHeads += headList[*i];
        totalTails += tailList[*i];
    }
    cout << "It took: " << (double)(clock() - tStart) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds to calculate and execute this program.\n";
    outputFile << "Total number of heads: " << totalHeads << " Total number of tails: " << totalTails << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Above is some code I've been messing with just to try out vectors (never used them in class). The code compiles in VS2015, but the program crashes with the following error: "Vector subscript out of range".

I assume this is telling me that at some point in my program a vector is attempting to be addressed at a location outside of its bounds. I haven't been able to tell whether the error is being thrown on my storage vectors or the iterator vector in the last for loop, and debugging doesn't work because the program crashes before it can begin to debug (weird that it isn't a compile time error then).

Comment: `vector<int> headList(100,0);` will create a vector with 100 entries. `.push_back` will append new entries (so by the end of the outer `for` loop the vectors will both have 201 elements). The second `for` loop should probably be just an `for (std::size_t i = 0; i < headList.size(); ++i) {...}` loop. As it is, you're using the entries in `headList` as indices into `headList` and `tailList`, which seems wrong. Try running this through a debugger and you'll see how these things can be problematic.

Comment: @Cornstalks, it can be trimmed further but it's a non issue now. The problem is already identified by Slava.

Comment: @Cornstalks, are you sure they would end up with 201 elements? The loop only goes from 0 to 100, and it's a single outer loop where the vectors are actually manipulated but maybe I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: @user3857017: It's the range 0 to 100, inclusive. Imagine if it was 0 to 10, inclusive. The numbers would be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. If you count that, you'll see there are 11 numbers. Same with 0 to 100 inclusive: there are 101 numbers within that range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator i = headList.begin(); i < headList.end(); i++)
{
    totalHeads += headList[*i];
    totalTails += tailList[*i];
}
```

iterator `i` iterates over all elements of `headList` vector. `*i` gives you that value (which is amount of heads in that iteration). You use that as an index for vectors `totalHeads` and `totalHeads` which seams to be wrong. Your loop should be:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < headList.size(); i++)
{
    totalHeads += headList[i];
    totalTails += tailList[i];
}
```

Note: though this loop:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator i = headList.begin(); i < headList.end(); i++)
```

works for random access iterator, it is more common to write it in form:

```
for (vector<int>::iterator i = headList.begin(); i != headList.end(); ++i)
```

this way it will also work for forward iterator and you may change container type without modifying much code. `++i` can be more efficient especially for iterator, not integral type.

Comment: That certainly did it! I definitely had a feeling that the iterator was the issue, and I pretty much used it just for the sake of trying out vectors. It's good to know that there's a better alternative though, thank you!